# Insert a row in PostgreSQL using Slick 3.2.2

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I have a Play-based application using PostgreSQL and Slick. I established a connection with the database (I've successfully generated the schema automatically).

I try to insert a row in a table:

```
val userdb = TableQuery[Userprofiles]
val insertion = userdb += (1, "firstname", "lastname", "address");
```

I got two compiler errors:

[reassignment to val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVcFd.png)

[too many arguments for method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPLLO.png)

How I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the query with `db.run` which will return a `scala.concurrent.Future` like this: `val future = db.run(userdb += (1, "firstname", "lastname", "address"))`

`db` is available by extending `HasDatabaseConfig` as shown in the [the Playframework docs.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlaySlick#DatabaseConfig-via-runtime-dependency-injection)

A great resource for learning Slick DB is [Essential Slick](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've found out the problem : the type Userprofiles was not the correct one ( automatically added import problem). The compiler messages from Intellij were incorrect.  Thanks for the Essential Slick link.